# How to sort a multiMap based on one of the multiple values in Java - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, hashmap, multimap

I am working on automation. I have following scenario:

1. There is a list of 40 countries.
2. My script goes to each country's detail page.
3. On detail page, there are 3 parameters for each country and I note them.
4. I am using multiMap for the purpose of saving values of 3 parameters.

   ```
   Multimap<String, Double> countryDataMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

   Double GDPdou = Double.valueOf(gdpSplit[0])*1000000000;
   countryDataMap.put(cText, GDPdou);

   Double intPop = Double.valueOf(popSplit[0])*1000000000;
   countryDataMap.put(cText, intPop);

   Double co2FVal = Double.valueOf(CO2val);
   countryDataMap.put(cText, co2FVal);
   ```

I am adding multiple values(3 separate parameters) for a single key(country). This process happens 40 times in a for loop.

I am using following code block to iterate through each, and display key,values.

```
Set<String> countryKeys = countryDataMap.keySet();

        for (String key : countryKeys) {
            System.out.println("Key = " + key);
            System.out.println("Values = " + countryDataMap.get(key));
        }
```

When I run my script for 4 countries for testing purpose, I am getting following output.

```
Key = Venezuela, RB
Values = [3.813E11, 3.069E7, 6.4]
Key = Japan
Values = [4.601E12, 1.271E8, 9.3]
Key = Italy
Values = [2.141E12, 6.079E7, 6.7]
Key = Korea, Rep.
Values = [1.41E12, 5.042E7, 11.8]
Key = Virgin Islands (U.S.)
Values = [1.996E9, 104200.0, null]
```

My work is on the right path up to this.

My question is , I want to sort my multimap on each of 3 values separately.

How can I sort my map based on first value of the 3 of each key?